# Joint probability associated to First Passage Time and the value random variables get when thorugh thershold

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I consider following situation described by 2-dimensional Langevin equation with Gaussian noise.(I deal with 2 dimensional case, but even if it is 1 dimensional or higher dimensional case, it will be good for me.)

$dx_{i} = A_i(x,t)dt + B_i(x,t)dW_i  (i=1,2)$

As initial condition, random variable $x_1,x_2$ at $t=t_{ini}$ is given, and these random variables are stochastic until the threshold $t=t_{th}$, then finally gets the values $x_{1,th},x_{2,th}$.

Here, I want to compute a joint probability $P_{joint}(t_{th},x_{1,th},x_{2,th})$, but I am confusing and stuck. I thought $P_{joint}$ is the product of $P_{FPT}(t_{th})$ and $P(x_{1,th},x_{2,th};t)$ apparently. $P_{FPT}(t_{th})$ is the probability density function(PDF) of the Frist Passage Time (which is the solution of Adjoint Fokker Planck equation), and $P(x_{1,th},x_{2,th};t)$ is the PDF taking $x_{1,th},x_{2,th}$ at $t$, solution of Fokker Planck equation. However, these two PDF are seemed not to be independent.

Generally speaking, How can we solve this kind of problem for joint probability.
Or is there any information or reference about this problem? Please let me know.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear eg. what do you mean by "random variable at the end"? Are you looking for the joint density if $(T,X_{T})$?

Comment: You can try adding in your post the specific SPDE/SDE you are dealing with. But yes, finding/simulating densities often goes through the Fokker-Plank equations which are  nonlinear pdes and thus often hard to solve explicitly (so instead people simulate them).

Comment: eg. "Neural network representation of the probability density function of
diffusion processes" in https://cims.nyu.edu/~wtu1/papers/2020Chaos.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and sorry for my blurred question. I will modify my question more concretely.

Comment: Even for 1-d sdes finding explicitly sde is often impossible (only simulation is possible), so I am not sure why you hope to compute it.  Yes the components $x_1,x_2$ will be correlated because the A,B coefficients force them to dependent on both Brownian motions.

Comment: I'm not looking to solve SDE concretely; rather, I'm interested in a general method for determining joint probabilities, if they exist. I mean, $P(x_1,x_2;t)$ will be determined by Fokker-Planck equation, also $P(t_{th})$ be determined by adjoint Fokker-Planck equation. So, what about joint probability $P(t_{th},x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: In that case you have to consider a Fokker Plank equation with boundary conditions eg. theorem 2 in "First passage time density of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck
process with broken drift" https://hal.science/hal-03159498/document

Comment: They in turn reference "Proposition 5.4.3.1" from  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84628-737-4. They do it for 1d but the proof doesn't look specific to 1d.

Answer (score 0):

In Proposition 5.4.3.1 in [Mathematical Methods for Financial Markets](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84628-737-4), they study the joint density of 1d-Brownian motion and a hitting time using a Fokker-Plank pde with boundary conditions.

In the article [First passage times of two-dimensional correlated processes:
Analytical results for the Wiener process and a numerical
method for diffusion processes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042715004859), they even study the 2d-version and contain various references for that case.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me some references. I will check that!